# Why '[False] or [True]' evaluates to [False] in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Why '[False] or [True]' evaluates to [False] in python3? Here is what I have tried.

```
[True] or [False] evaluates to [True]
[False] or [True] evaluates to [False]
[False] or True   evaluates to [False]
False or [True]   evaluates to [True]
False or True     evaluates to True
```

Why the or operator is no commutative?

Comment: Why should `or` be commutative for non-Boolean arguments? `3 or 4` is `3`, but `4 or 3` is `4`. How would you change that to be commutative?

Comment: Nevermind. I expect python to evaluate both 3 and 4 to True and return True. Turns out or operator is nothing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Non-empty sequences like `[True]` & `[False]` are treated as true-ish. It doesn't matter what's in the sequence, only if it's empty will be be false-ish.

2) The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Now apply these findings to your expressions:

```
[True] or [False] evaluates to True, return first, [True]
[False] or [True] evaluates to True, return first, [False]
[False] or True   evaluates to True, return first, [False]
False or [True]   evaluates to True, return second, [True]
False or True     evaluates to True, return second, True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know if it is a bug or a feature, but this rule just makes or operator so counterintuitive in that it is now non-commutative.

Comment: Also, I find that '' or [] evaluates to [], while [] or '' evaluate to ''. This does not seem to fit your description. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: My explanation was a bit simplified. The complete method is this: The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Comment: You can read about the behaviour here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or